# In what file does the binding of request key to the service container of Request Facade happen in laravel?

Tags: laravel, facade, laravel-service-container

In the laravel Request facade we have the key 'request' being returned. To my understanding this is the key that is bound to the service container to resolve a class. In which file do we have the binding logic of the key happening?

```
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Support\Facades;
/*
 * @see \Illuminate\Http\Request
 */
class Request extends Facade
{
    /**
     * Get the registered name of the component.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected static function getFacadeAccessor()
    {
        return 'request';
    }
}
```